# A question on completeness of $\mathbb R$ and countability of infinite sets

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $x \in \mathbb R$\ $\mathbb Q$ and $A$ is a set of real numbers such that $x \notin A$ and $\sup A=x$ , then do we necessarily have that $A$ is uncountable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Consider $A$ as a set of increasing rationals converging to a fixed irrational number. Then the set $A$ is countable.

Example:

$A$ to be the set of $a_n$'s such that $a_1=3,\ a_2=3.1,\ a_3=3.14,...$ all the rational numbers obtained by truncating the decimal expansion of $\pi$.